# Want to make dynamic pages indexable using react cra

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

So i have this social media app with multiple pages, it's all created with create react app with context api and react-router for routing and laravel for backend. Now, google won't be able to index these dynamic pages, i have tried pre rendring the pages using react-snapshot, currently looking into next js.
i know react has this react dom server, will it be good idea to hook up another server just for pre-rendring the page before sending it to the client.

Is there any other way to do ssr with cra.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google should index your website. please check your `robots.txt` file and also try to provide `sitemap.xml` for better crawling for google.

Also, there are some issues with using `react-snap` and that is you render the page at build time and your site render won't change if you read your content from the database and update your database while you didn't rebuild your app.
you can use `after.js` but `next.js` have a bigger community and more tutorials out there so I recommend you use `next.js`.

Also, there is a tool named [`prerender.io`](https://github.com/prerender/prerender)(open source) and you can serve rendered page to search engine bots this is the easiest way in my opinion and do not have the downside of using `react-snap`

Comment: it doesnt have solution for react, it has solution for nodejs

Answer (score 2):

First things first, Google is able to index client-side rendered pages.
I think next.js is a good choice for SSR, but you can also look at [razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle) - maybe you can retrofit that to your CRA setup.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely try this. Also, if google can index client-side rendered pages properly, can't i just use cra then ?

Comment: @geekonaut what would be the pros/cons of using next.js vs cra?

Comment: Both are fine, next.js has the advantage of giving you a lot of tooling and docs around SSR out of the box.

Comment: it doesnt have any proper examples